# Sending Bitmap Image from Google app engine to android via GCM

Tags: android, bitmap, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send images (both post image, and profile pictures, like facebook). 
when im trying to send those images (Bitmap encoded), the gcm is ignoring my request, with no particular reason.

here's a code that's working:

```
query = ndb.gql("""SELECT * FROM GCM_Registration_Table""")
    i = 0
    tokens = []
    for q in query:
        tokens.append(q.token)
        i += 1

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('android.googleapis.com')
conn.connect()
conn.set_debuglevel(1)
body = {}
body['data'] = {
    'message': 'this is a post message',
    'post_id': post.post_id,
    'publisher': post.publisher,
    'message_text': post.message_text,
    'color': post.color,
    'race': post.race,
    'size': post.size,
    'zone': post.zone,
    'sex': post.sex,
    'publish_time': str(post.publish_time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    }
body['registration_ids'] = tokens
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Authorization': 'key=' \
           + api_key}
print 'Send data \n' + str(body)
conn.request('POST', '/gcm/send', json.dumps(body), headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

however when i'm adding the line:

```
'profile_picture': post.profile_picture
```

it doesn't work.

any ideas? or sol?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but make sure you're taking this into consideration: https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=gcm+payload+size

Comment: I was thinking about it as well, and your probably right.
but i do i turn this over. I mean if whatsapp for example, sends out picture, they're sending it via GCM kind of messaging

Comment: What's you end goal though? Why don't you use something like OneSignal ? They have an API which let you send push notifications easily, and they let you attach all kinds of things to it, including images (as urls i believe, not as binary). It's simple and it's free or at least the number of free limits are pretty high for common use cases ... https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So you can not send images via GCM because of its sizes.

so the simple solution is sending the "Post id" and then request the post by its id from the server.

Thanks!